# How to find last location using android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I'm using the following code to get my last know location, but it is not working

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteia();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

if(location!=null){
    onLocationChanged(location);
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say given the lack of error information. Just a guess ... do you have these in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```